# How to send an HTML email using SMTP in PHP

Tags: php, html, email, smtp

I've been able to send an email using SMTP in PHP, but when I try to change the Content Type to HTML, the email doesn't get delivered. This is the code I'm trying to use:

```
    require_once "Mail.php";

    $from = "FPM <forms@fpmofames.com>";
    $from_name = "FPM";

    $host = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";

    $subject = "Subject";
    $message = "Message";

    $to = "<example@example.com>";
    $headers = array ('From' => $from,
        'To' => $to,
        'Subject' => $subject,
        'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
        'Content-Type' => "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    );

    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
        array ('host' => $host,
            'auth' => true,
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password));

    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $message);
```

If I take the 'Content-Type' argument out of the headers, it sends the message just fine. I don't know why adding that causes a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem most likely lies in the Mail class, but since we don't know what Mail class you're using, it's difficult to answer.  If you're not already doing so, I'd really think about using PHPMailer: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Answer (score 5):

I did some research, then I made my own code to send mail with HTML formatting using SMTP authentication. See here:

```
<?php 
require_once "Mail.php";
$url = $_GET['baseUrl']; // source url
$success = false;
$senderName = isset( $_GET['txtname'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_GET['txtname'] ) : "";
$senderEmail = isset( $_GET['txtemail'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_GET['txtemail'] ) : "";
$msg = isset( $_GET['txtDesc'] ) ? preg_replace( "/(From:|To:|BCC:|CC:|Subject:|Content-Type:)/", "", $_GET['txtDesc'] ) : "";
$body = '<table width="400" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Name:</th>
    <th scope="col">'.$senderName.'</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Company:</th>
    <td scope="col">'.$_GET['txtCompany'].'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Phone:</th>
    <td>'.$_GET['txtphone'].'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">E-mail:</th>
    <td>'.$senderEmail.'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">URL:</th>
    <td>'.$url.'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Massage:</th>
    <td>'.$msg.'</td>
  </tr>
</table>';

 $from = $senderName."<".$senderEmail.">";
 $to = "Contact ManagerHR<info@aequitas-infotech.com>";
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $host = "XXX.host.com";
 $username = "username@host.com";
 $password = "*****";
 /* MIME-Version should be "1.0rn" and Content-Type should be "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1rn" to send an HTML Email */
$headers = array ('MIME-Version' => '1.0rn',
        'Content-Type' => "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1rn",
        'From' => $from,
        'To' => $to,
        'Subject' => $subject
     );
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
   array ('host' => $host,
     'auth' => true,
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password));
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
 if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
   echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
  } else {
      header('Location: '.$url); // redirect to url where from inquiry made
   //echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create the mail body via mime object. And pear will handle it from there.
Ex:

```
     $crlf = "\n";
    // Creating the Mime message
    $mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);

    // Setting the body of the email
    $mime->setTXTBody($text);
    $mime->setHTMLBody($html);
   ...
    $body = $mime->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Send your HTML email using SMTP in PHP to 2 or 3 different emails
 WORKING 100%

```
<?php

require_once "Mail.php";

$host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$username = "example@gmail.com";
$password = "password";
$port = "465";

$to  = '1-to-example@example.com' . ', '; 
$to  = '2-to-example@example.com' . ', '; 
$to  = '3-to-example@example.com' . ', '; 

$email_from = "from-example@example.com";
$email_subject = "Your Subject";

$email_body = "**<html> <body>**"; 
$email_body .= "<strong> Your HTML code </strong>";
$email_body .= "**</body></html>**";


$headers = array ('From' => $email_from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => 
$email_subject, 'Reply-To' => $email_address , 'MIME-Version' => '1.0', 'Content-Type' => "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'port' => $port, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $email_body);

?>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question about the `Content-Type`? Besides, you should use `.=` to concatenate the email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You can complete in two steps.

Step 1: Put code in your file:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Step:2 Download this included file in given URL.
Url: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.git

and click on **clone or download**  button
and set folder your system.

Answer (score 0):

Write content type in a first line of header just like this

```
$to = "<example@example.com>"; $headers = array ('Content-Type' => "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1", 'From' => $from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject, 'MIME-Version' => '1.0' );
```

This is working for me..